# Google Analytics - Incorrect total users

Tags: google-analytics

We've just set up Google Analytics for a new intranet - and the total users metric is incorrect. We have around 3,500 staff and are getting around 3,500-4,000 users per day, which is fine - accounting for users with multiple browsers. For a two week span, however, GA is returning 10,000 users, which simply can't be correct, knowing the size of the organisation.

Is this a common issue? Any fix out there?

Answer (score 0):

if your work computers are set to clear cookies periodically or simply doesn't keep them, then GA account accurately track the unique number of users, since it relies on cookies to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refine the count of users, you should think about **overriding the GA "clientId" with a "userId"**. Whatever the tracker generates multiple "clientId" (new tracker cookie), a unique identifier related to each connected user (from a database for example) can be sent as a "userId". Its use should decrease the number of users and reflect more the reality.

Here is a sample code to set a "userId" with the "analytics.js" tracker:

```
ga('set', 'userId', '<?php echo $USER_ID; ?>');
```

For this use, you must enable tracking "userId" into your Google Analytics account: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en